# ssh-add does not work inside docker image

Tags: ssh, docker, sftp

We are connecting to a remote server via SFTP. The connection  requires  SSH keys and a passphrase. To eliminate the passphrase prompt when SFTP is being executed, we are using ssh-add via script ,to add the pass phrase.

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
pass=$(cat $2)

expect << EOF
spawn ssh-add $1
expect "Enter passphrase"
send "$pass\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

This executes fine in docker and I get the 'Identity added' message.
However when SFTP is run subsequently  it asks for the passphrase.
What could be wrong?

Comment: If this script is run in the usual way by just typing its (relative) path it runs in a subshell and the envvars set by `eval $(ssh-agent)` exist only for an instant in that subshell. Try using `source script` or `. script` depending on your shell. But *if* the password is in a file *on the same filesystem* you might as well just decrypt the privatekey in the first place.

Comment: when you already have password stored in the file alongside with the key, there is no gain in using encrypted key. Just remove the passphrase from the key and profit. Or use `sshpass`.